# How to locate the last row of cells in a range which matches using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

There is one column in a table where names of factories are shown but I only need the data for a specific factory name(let's say factory "Australia").

My idea is to locate the first and last rows which match because the data for the same factory are always presented in a consecutive manner. In this way, I can get the range of cells which match up to my search.

Locating the first matched row position is quite easy but I get stuck in getting the last matched row position.

Here is the code regarding this section:

```
Sub Search()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim searchStr As String
Dim lastRow As Long, firstRow as Long
Dim tableRange As range

Set sh = Worksheets("Total order")
searchStr = "Australia"
Set tableRange = sh.range("B:B").Find(what:=searchStr, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
firstRow = tableRange.Row

End Sub
```

An example of the table dealt with:

[image]

Comment: `Set tableRange = tableRange.Resize(Application.Countif(sh.range("B:B"), searchStr))` will give you B4:B7

Comment: @Tim that's cool....

Comment: @TimWilliams 
Thanks a lot but can I ask how to access this range?(or only access B7 from this range)
I want to save the row position in "lastRow". However, when I set lastRow = tableRange.Row following your code, it only shows "4".

Comment: You could do: `FirstRow = tableRange.Row` : `LastRow = FirstRow + tableRange.Rows.Count - 1` or just: `LastRow = tableRange.Row + tableRange.Rows.Count - 1`.

Comment: You already have tableRange as a reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Refer to the Range from the Cell of the First to the Cell of the Last Occurrence of a String in a Column

**A Side Note**

- The [`Range.Find method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) is kind of tricky. For example, you may not be aware that in your code the search starts from cell `B2` (which is even preferable in this case), and using `xlValues` may result in undesired results if rows are hidden (probably not important).

**Usage**

- Using the function, according to the screenshot, you could (after `searchStr = "Australia"`) use:

  ```
  Set tableRange = refRangeFirstLast(sh.Columns("B"), searchStr)
  ```

  to refer to the range `B4:B7`, or use:

  ```
  Set tableRange = refRangeFirstLast(sh.Columns("B"), searchStr).Offset(, -1).Resize(, 4)
  ```

  to refer to the range `A4:D7`.

**The Code**

```
Function refRangeFirstLast( _
    ByVal ColumnRange As Range, _
    ByVal SearchString As String) _
As Range
    If Not ColumnRange Is Nothing Then
        With ColumnRange
            Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = _
                .Find(SearchString, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
            If Not FirstCell Is Nothing Then
                Dim LastCell As Range: Set LastCell = _
                    .Find(SearchString, , xlFormulas, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
                Set refRangeFirstLast = .Worksheet.Range(FirstCell, LastCell)
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function

Sub refRangeFirstLastTEST()
    Const SearchString As String = "Australia"
    Dim ColumnRange As Range
    Set ColumnRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Total order").Columns("B")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = refRangeFirstLast(ColumnRange, SearchString)
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print rg.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "The reference could not be created.", vbExclamation, "Fail?"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great stuff @VBasic2008